# Access to Docker Container Port

Tags: docker

Im running boot2docker. I have a container running which Ive opened port 8000 for. i.e

```
docker@boot2docker:/home/djangoapp/testtools$ docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                                                              COMMAND                CREATED             STATUS                    PORTS                      NAMES
4c52d46227f2        felix001/djangoapp:1.0                                             "/bin/bash"            22 hours ago        Up 22 hours               127.0.0.1:8000->8000/tcp   ecstatic_noyce
```

However if I try to access the port I get a RST,

```
docker@boot2docker:/home/djangoapp/testtools$ curl http://127.0.0.1:8000
curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer
```

Any ideas ?

Comment: Have you actually exposed the port with `-p`? It's not clear from your question.

Comment: Issue was due to using the 127.0.0.1 address

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the IP address of the boot2docker VM. Usually `192.168.59.103`.

Comment: That was going to be my answer, except from the question it appears that the OP may already be *logged into* the boot2docker VM.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried seeing if the server is running?
First, you are going to need to root into the container:

```
docker exec -it 4c52d46227f2 bash
```

Then, check if the server is running:

```
python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

And, it might be something else other than `manage.py` for your container, but you get the idea.

Here is another article to help out to understand the manual process and setup: https://ochronus.com/docker-primer-django/

Comment: Yep check and its showing as running,
127.0.0.1:8000          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      198/python